# Can I use an environment variable like hostname from the shell in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf

I am trying to have all my webservers write their logs to a shared storage system. I'd like to use a system environment variable so that I don't have to maintain 20+ httpd.conf files. My httpd.conf files are part of my deployment, we do this so that if we need to change something all hosts get that change.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

ErrorLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /data/logs/apache/${hostname}_error_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400"

where hostname is the same thing returned by the shell command, eg:

user@server1.domain@01:47:17:~ $> hostname
server1.domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that because I am using the | through to rotatelogs I should try $HOSTNAME and whuduya know.

ErrorLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs /data/logs/apache/$HOSTNAME.error_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400"

works great :)